# Stored procedure in Entity framework with multiple parameters in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am new in entity framework and mvc3.how can i execute Stored procedure in Entity framework with multiple parameters in mvc3.

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: have u return any value from store procedure  ?

Comment: @Erik..its 4.0 entity framework.@Rajpurohit...no i dont want to return any value from stored procedure.it is a procedure for inserting some values in the database

Comment: There are many more questions about this. You don't show any research effort. It's really not hard to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends if you are using code first or not. I do agree with the folks above you could've probably easily researched this but I'll provide an overview here so it's all in one spot to review as there are several options to consider.

With code first in the latest version of EF 6 Beta, you can execute stored procs as part of code-first as described in the docs [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Insert/Update/Delete%20Stored%20Procedure%20Mapping)
Prior to EFv6 you could use the following to execute a proc in your code and map to an entity

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>
```

If you aren't using code first, you can map in the designer as explained by Julie Lerman many places, but one easy link is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx)

Comment: I got it by.  context.procedure_name(param1,param2).Actualy i was not able to find the stored procedure name after context.The reason behind was that i had not imported the function,After importing i got it working.thanks to all for helping